# CompileAssemblyFromDom throws access denied exception

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, compilation, code-generation

The code:

```
using (var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
{
    var compilerParameter = new CompilerParameters(
                _assemblies, assemblyName, false)
            {
                GenerateInMemory = true,
                CompilerOptions = "/optimize"
            };

    var compilerResults = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(
                compilerParameter, templateResults.Select(r => r.GeneratedCode)
                .ToArray());
}
```

It throws exception: CS1567 Error generating Win32 resource: Access is denied.

What does it mean?

Comment: Run procmon and filter for errors so you can see what got denied.

Comment: Got it.

    CreateFile C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\CSCA77DD801384044AFAFB245A7DED3D4DB.TMP ACCESS DENIED

Comment: But still have no idea why it uses this location C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\ ?

Comment: Get it works! See answer for details..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get this working. The problem was that assemblyName was file name not path, so I changed

```
assemblyName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), assemblyName);
```

And it start working!

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, but AssemblyName didn't fix it for me. I was able to fix it by using TempFiles parameter. Also, for some reason it does not work in the temp path itself, only works when I create my own subfolder there.

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\mysubfolder";
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);

var parameters = new CompilerParameters(includeAssemblies.ToArray())
                {                    
                    GenerateInMemory = true,
                    TempFiles = new TempFileCollection(tempPath)
                };
```