# AccessDenied(Win32.Ressource) for CodeDom

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

we have an IIS running, where we deploy code.

Now I want to generate a .exe-file dynamically and return it as `FileResult`, this is where I need `CodeDomProvider`.

Code-Sample:

```
CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(
    new string[] {
            @"assembly..."
    });
   parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
```

I get 2 Errors(`CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sb.ToString())`):

- "error CS1567: Fehler beim Generieren der Win32-Ressource: Zugriff verweigert " => Access denied , Win32.Ressource
- "warning CS1610: Die temporäre Datei 'c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\someFile.TMP', die für die Win32-Standardressource verwendet wird, kann nicht gelöscht werden -- Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden."=> some file(never seen), could not be found

Is there something I missed, or I should care for when using CodeDom on server side(this code works with console applications)  ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with access denied nearly always is because the pool user hasnt access

Comment: Ok, I found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816449/compileassemblyfromdom-throws-access-denied-exception Thanks